# Kafka-node keeps disconnecting and reconnecting with "Kafka producer error: NestedError refreshBrokenMetadata"

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-node

The nodejs server is launched with pm2 as a one instance fork.

My kafka options:

```
export const kafkaTopics = ['chat'];
export const kafkaOptions: ConsumerGroupOptions = {
  kafkaHost,
  groupId: 'test-chat',
  batch: undefined,
  sessionTimeout: 15000,
  protocol: ['roundrobin'],
  encoding: 'utf8',
  fromOffset: 'latest',
  outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
};
```

Client:

```
kafkaClient = new Client({
  kafkaHost,
  idleConnection: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

Producer:

```
kafkaConsumer = new ConsumerGroup(options, topics);
```

Consumer:

```
kafkaProducer = new HighLevelProducer(kafkaClient);
```

```
NestedError: refreshMetadata failed
Kafka producer error: NestedError: refreshBrokenMetadata
```

Any suggestions why it keeps happening?